# Error when using XHProf and XHGui

Tags: php, osx-mountain-lion, zlib, xhprof

I have installed and configured XHGui as per the instructions here:

http://www.sitepoint.com/the-need-for-speed-profiling-with-xhprof-and-xhgui/

However, when I try to profile a page I see an error inserting into the details table (have truncated this as there is a large string of binary/compressed data):

```
Failed to insert: INSERT INTO `details` (`id`, `url`, `c_url`, `timestamp`, `server name`, `perfdata`, `type`, `cookie`, `post`, `get`, `pmu`, `wt`, `cpu`, `server_id`, `aggregateCalls_include`) VALUES('5278f06a19b9d', '/whats-on/?', '/whats-on/?', FROM_UNIXTIME('1383657576'), 'local.site2', 'x^���r$Iv%\n�K?����v����/?���������-��-�����~��j�\\/�g��>��X����O���~���o��mv���������������r9�p~�=��_��>�N_���jI�/�Wt�bqX�������Sy��S��K�u��:?g��K�6��p�����ӇOw�_>ষ�˄;.|�%��X���;n�>�����������-A\0ܞ/��\n\Z����������;C��om?\r;|a %5\0^�p��+z��A���rk��×�a��L\'OFю@X8�\"��7�\r��ah=���J�\'\n��Q���?�0�?��b\ZN�����rzz�����ߝ�O�Al=7�
```

I believe zlib compression is being used and that my PHP install was compiled with zlib support:

```
'./configure' '--prefix=/usr/local/php5' '--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/php5/php.d' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-zlib=/usr' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr' '--with-gd' '--with-ldap' '--with-xmlrpc' '--enable-exif' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sqlite-utf8' '--enable-wddx' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-sockets' '--with-bz2=/usr' '--enable-zip' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--with-iodbc' '--with-mhash' '--enable-fpm' '--with-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' '--enable-pcntl' '--enable-dtrace' '--with-icu-dir=/usr/local/php5' '--with-mssql=shared,/usr/local/php5' '--with-pdo-dblib=shared,/usr/local/php5' '--with-libxml-dir=shared,/usr/local/php5' '--with-xsl=shared,/usr/local/php5' '--with-imap=../imap-2007f' '--with-kerberos=/usr' '--with-imap-ssl=/usr' '--with-gettext=/usr/local/php5' '--with-curl=shared,/usr/local/php5' '--with-png-dir=/usr/local/php5' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/php5' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/php5' '--with-pgsql=shared,/usr/local/php5' '--with-pdo-pgsql=shared,/usr/local/php5' '--with-mcrypt=shared,/usr/local/php5' '--with-tidy=/usr/local/php5' '--with-gmp=shared,/usr/local/php5' '--with-readline=shared,/usr/local/php5'
```

Anyone seen this before or know what is going on? Its running on localhost (Mountain Lion with [Liip OSX PHP](http://php-osx.liip.ch/) - PHP 5.4

**UPDATE**

I increased the server_id field length and ran the profile again. Now getting:

Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'pmu' at row 1 as a result of this query:

```
INSERT INTO `details` (`id`, `url`, `c_url`, `timestamp`, `server name`, `perfdata`, `type`, `cookie`, `post`, `get`, `pmu`, `wt`, `cpu`, `server_id`, `aggregateCalls_include`) VALUES('5279085839571', '/whats-on/?', '/whats-on/?', FROM_UNIXTIME('1383663629'), 'local.mysitename', 'x^��\0\0�\0�', '1', 'a:1:{s:8:\"_profile\";s:1:\"1\";}', 'a:0:{}', 'a:0:{}', '', '', '', 'localhost', '')
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE `details` (
  `id` char(17) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `server name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `perfdata` mediumblob,
  `type` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cookie` blob,
  `post` blob,
  `get` blob,
  `pmu` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `wt` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `cpu` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `server_id` char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 't11',
  `aggregateCalls_include` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `url` (`url`),
  KEY `c_url` (`c_url`),
  KEY `cpu` (`cpu`),
  KEY `wt` (`wt`),
  KEY `pmu` (`pmu`),
  KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few questions:

- *What database backend is PDO using? MySQL? Other? If it's MySQL try the MySQL(i) adapter?* Data is being stored in **MySQL**
- If you copy/paste the query (omitting the blob data for simplicity) does the query execute, or even get a more verbose error? Does it just work?
- Does the backend you're using support blob nicely? **MySQL Does**
- Can you show the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for your details table?

I don't think the compression is the issue, it would have failed earlier, like around here: https://github.com/preinheimer/xhprof/blob/master/xhprof_lib/utils/xhprof_runs.php#L434

Taking your updated `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and query, I get:

```
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE `details` (
    ->   `id` char(17) NOT NULL,
    ->   `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `c_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ->   `server name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `perfdata` mediumblob,
    ->   `type` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `cookie` blob,
    ->   `post` blob,
    ->   `get` blob,
    ->   `pmu` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `wt` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `cpu` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `server_id` char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 't11',
    ->   `aggregateCalls_include` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    ->   KEY `url` (`url`),
    ->   KEY `c_url` (`c_url`),
    ->   KEY `cpu` (`cpu`),
    ->   KEY `wt` (`wt`),
    ->   KEY `pmu` (`pmu`),
    ->   KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`)
    -> ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `details` (`id`, `url`, `c_url`, `timestamp`, `server name`, `perfdata`, `type`, `cookie`, `post`, `get`, `pmu`, `wt`, `cpu`, `server_id`, `aggregateCalls_include`) VALUES('5279085839571', '/whats-on/?', '/whats-on/?', FROM_UNIXTIME('1383663629'), 'local.mysitename', 'x^��\0\0�\0�', '1', 'a:1:{s:8:\"_profile\";s:1:\"1\";}', 'a:0:{}', 'a:0:{}', '', '', '', 'localhost', '') ;
Query OK, 1 row affected, 4 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: thanks. It was set to PDO but I switched to mysqli - same error. Not sure what you mean by 'the backend I'm using'? The page under test is part of a Wordpress based site.

Comment: I ran without the large blob info in a mysql client - It complained about the length of the server_id field which I increased. I have updated the question with the remaining error (data is at least now being written to the table)

Comment: thanks, I've added a new question regarding show create table, alsp, what happens if you c/p the query into MySQL directly?

Comment: see above re running query directly

Comment: Your query pair works for me, do they fail for you at the command line?

Comment: Perhaps this is down to MySQL version then? this is 5.6.11 on Mountain Lion

Comment: I'm using a mysql gui (Sequel Pro) - thats where I am getting the additional errors from. They do fail for me, yes.

Comment: K, Things are still looking good on my side, with SequelPro, and MySQL 5.6 http://screencast.com/t/c0xTxxfBJ

Comment: Its certainly strange that yours is behaving differently. Many thanks for trying to help but as I have now spent the day debugging the tool i hoped would help me with some debugging, I think I give up at this point. :-/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40583/discussion-between-codecowboy-and-preinheimer)